# Spring and Thymeleaf - Cannot initialize: no template resolvers have been set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am currently working on a Spring Boot application.Am getting error when trying to create an Email Service.

application.properties :

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/static/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=true
```

The index.html is resolved from main controller when application url is accessed.But the email template is not getting resolved.

MainController:

```
  @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home() {
            return "index";
        }
```

EmailService :

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").build();     
         // Prepare the evaluation context
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);        
         ctx.setVariable("saveComplaints", saveComplaintEntity);

         // Prepare message using a Spring helper
          MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
          MimeMessageHelper message =
             new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8"); // true = multipart
         message.setSubject("Example HTML email with inline image");
         message.setFrom("****@gmail.com");
         message.setTo("*****@gmail.com");

         // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
          String htmlContent = templateEngine.process("email", ctx);
          message.setText(htmlContent, true); // true = isHtml


         // Send mail
         mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

The "email" template name refers to email.html file which is palced at the same location as that of index.html (classpath:/static/)

Error :

```
nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot initialize: no template resolvers have been set] with root cause:
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot initialize: no template resolvers have been set
```

Edit:

smtp configuration :

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username= *****@gmail.com   
spring.mail.password= *****
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.defaultEncoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Error serving mail :

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect] with root cause
```

complete error trace:

```
 2017-11-06 03:48:57.827 ERROR 38292 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:331) ~[javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238) ~[javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2084) ~[javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:712) ~[javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) ~[javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:501) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:421) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.demo.email.service.EmailService.sendMail(EmailService.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.demo.email.controller.MailController.sendMail(MailController.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

Solution :

```
@AutoWired 
TemplateEngine templateEngine
```

insted of creatig new  SpringTemplateEngine object.

```
@Autowired
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender
```

insted of creating new JavaMailSenderImpl object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this `SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();` where you are creating a new template engine, you have to `autowire` the one created by Spring Boot by using `@AutoWired TemplateEngine templateEngine`

For emails from Spring Boot app, I will recommend [this](https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools) library which makes sending emails amazingly simple!!

Comment: Thanks for your help,it solved my issue,thymeleaft resolved the file.But upon serving mail am getting permission denied error.I have edited the post

Comment: @arunabraham Sorry to plug in my own blog post. I see you are using Gmail as the smtp server. I had blogged on [how to use gmail as smtp server](https://sanaulla.info/2017/09/15/using-gmail-as-smtp-server-from-java-spring-boot-apps/). So that might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,will look into the post

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if it's been resolved.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve the Permission denied: error with the configuration I have provided in the post.I had googled on this.- I had set Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in VM(eclipse), but not getting resolved.Could you please tell me why this issue occurs?

Comment: Provide complete stack trace. If its due to an SSL error you have to run InstallCert program and install the certificate in your java installation. Visit [this](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) to know more about InstallCert

Comment: I have edited the question with complete error trace.Kindy look into it

Comment: Ok I got the issue. You dont create a new `JavaMailSenderImpl` instead use `@Autowired` For more info read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-email.html). If you are creating a new `JavaMailSenderImpl` then you need to read the properties and set the host and port. Otherwise its using the defaults now.

Comment: Thanks for your great help, it got resolved.But when I hit the mail service,  execution is still at line mailSender.send(mimeMessage); and doesn't end(not going to next line for a long time and I have to terminate program), not getting why

Comment: Yes for that you need to follow my blog post. I have faced similar issues and resolved it and thereby ended up with a blog post. Even if you are not using the library I mentioned, you can just copy the properties I provided in `application.properties`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158311/discussion-between-arun-abraham-and-mohamedsanaulla).

Comment: Email service working now,used the same code posted,with the changes you had  mentioned.Thanks @ MohamedSanaulla .

Answer (score 1):

In my case I tried @MohamedSanaulla's suggestion and added the following to my Spring `@Configuration` class:

```
@Autowired
public void configureSpringTemplateEngine(SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine) {
    springTemplateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
}
```

But then I started getting duplicate dialect-related exceptions about `LayoutDialect` being declared twice. So I just removed it entirely (so, neither trying to instantiate a new `SpringTemplateEngine`, nor trying to configure the one provided to me by Boot by adding `LayoutDialect` to it) and it worked fined.

Answer (score 0):

I did some thing like this to avoid the issue.

`public PdfCreationServiceImpl(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) { this.templateEngine = templateEngine; ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver(); templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/"); templateResolver.setSuffix(".html"); templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML); templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver); this.templateEngine = templateEngine; }`